# database connection Crystal report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports, database-connection

I have mysql database in windows form app C# and I want to use crystal report for reporting but  I want to connect to DB without report wizard because I want to my application be independent to a database server address and my application has this option that can set database server address to connect  .how can reach to this goal ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this article](http://www.alexlea.me/2007/08/howto-read-crystalreportviewer-report.html), I think you could pass the `connectionStrings` manually in your case :

```
// Get document 
ReportDocument doc = this.CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument;

// Set connection string from config in existing LogonProperties
doc.DataSourceConnections[0].LogonProperties.Set("Connection String",
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);

// Add existing properties to a new collection
NameValuePairs2 logonProps = new NameValuePairs2();
logonProps.AddRange(doc.DataSourceConnections[0].LogonProperties);

// Set our new collection to be the defaults
// This causes Crystal Reports to actually use our changed properties
doc.DataSourceConnections[0].SetLogonProperties(logonProps);
```